# How to set secondary x-axis and its range in plotly graph with subfigures?

Tags: python, plotly, histogram

does anyone know how to set a secondary x-axis and also its range in plotly?

I am trying to show a vertical histogram here but it is currently still too small

[Vertical histogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCCk9.png)

[image]

```html
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
from plotly.graph_objs.layout import YAxis,XAxis,Margin

x1 = np.linspace(0, 4, 41)
y1 = (x1-2)**3+2
y2 = x1*0+2

x1_sample = np.random.normal(2,0.3,5000)
y1_sample = (x1_sample-2)**3+2
data = np.column_stack((x1_sample, y1_sample))
df_hist = pd.DataFrame(data = data, columns = ['x1_sample', 'y1_sample'])


fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2, specs = [[{"secondary_y": True}, {"secondary_y": True}]], horizontal_spacing=0.2)

# Subplot 1
## Line
fig.update_yaxes(range = [0, 4], dtick = 1, secondary_y=False)
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x = x1 , y = y1, mode='lines'),
    row = 1, col = 1
)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x = x1, y = y2, mode = 'lines'),
    row = 1, col = 1
)

## Histogram
fig.update_yaxes(range = [0, 0.5], dtick = 0.1, secondary_y=True)
fig.add_trace(
    go.Histogram(x = df_hist['x1_sample'], histnorm='probability', nbinsx=40),
    secondary_y=True,
    row = 1, col = 1
)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Histogram(y = df_hist['y1_sample'], histnorm='probability', nbinsy=40),
    row = 1, col = 1
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get what you need in your example, just add the following lines to your setup:

```
fig.update_layout(xaxis2= {'anchor': 'y', 'overlaying': 'x', 'side': 'top'})
fig.data[3].update(xaxis='x2')
fig.update_layout(xaxis2_range=[-0,0.6])
```

Line 1 sets up a secondary x-axis, while line 2 assigns a trace to it. I'm assuming `fig.data[3]` is the correct trace but you can check that for yourself. Line 3, unsuprisingly, sets the range of the secondary x-axis.

#### Plot

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
from plotly.graph_objs.layout import YAxis,XAxis,Margin


x1 = np.linspace(0, 4, 41)
y1 = (x1-2)**3+2
y2 = x1*0+2

x1_sample = np.random.normal(2,0.3,5000)
y1_sample = (x1_sample-2)**3+2
data = np.column_stack((x1_sample, y1_sample))
df_hist = pd.DataFrame(data = data, columns = ['x1_sample', 'y1_sample'])


fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2, specs = [[{"secondary_y": True}, {"secondary_y": True}]],
                    horizontal_spacing=0.2,
                    shared_xaxes = False)

# Subplot 1
## Line
fig.update_yaxes(range = [0, 4], dtick = 1, secondary_y=False)
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x = x1 , y = y1, mode='lines'),
    row = 1, col = 1
)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x = x1, y = y2, mode = 'lines'),
    row = 1, col = 1
)

## Histogram
fig.update_yaxes(range = [0, 0.5], dtick = 0.1, secondary_y=True)
fig.add_trace(
    go.Histogram(x = df_hist['x1_sample'], histnorm='probability', nbinsx=40),
    secondary_y=True,
    row = 1, col = 1
)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Histogram(y = df_hist['y1_sample'], histnorm='probability', nbinsy=40),
    row = 1, col = 1
)

fig.update_layout(xaxis2= {'anchor': 'y', 'overlaying': 'x', 'side': 'top'})
fig.data[3].update(xaxis='x2')
fig.update_layout(xaxis2_range=[-0,0.6])


fig.show()
```

Comment: That's just what I needed. Thank you.

Comment: @tarnow If this was exactly what you needed, why did you un-accept the answer?

Comment: I tried to apply your presented approach for subplot row=1, col=2. Unfortunately, applying the solution (and changing the parameters) you provided did not result in a working script for me. I actually added another answer a couple days ago in which I specified my problem which was unfortunately deleted by another user. I assume I will just post a new stand-alone question. Sorry for the confusion and thank you for your original answer (accepted answer again).

Comment: @tarnow I see. Raising that as a new question instead would be a good idea!